# Check if user is logged in with Flask-Login in template

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

When I log a user in, I set `logged_in` in the session, then check this value in the template.  Is there a better way to check if the user is logged in with Flask-Login?

```
session['logged_in'] = True
login_user(user)
```

```
{% if session['logged_in'] %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Quoting the [example on flask-login](http://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#login-example):

> It’s that simple. You can then access the logged-in user with the current_user proxy, which is available in every template:
>
> ```
> {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
>   Hi {{ current_user.name }}!
> {% endif %}
> ```